# Variable o metodo no definida en Ruby ¿Como lo solucion con metaprogramacion?

Tags: ruby

Buenas que tal, estoy trantado de definir un comportamiento a la Clase Persona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito hacer es que al colocarle el "transaccional" dentro del cuerpo de la clase dinamicamente me incluya un mixin a la clase o ejecute algun metodo. Entiendo que se puede hacer con metaprogramación pero no se como.Espero que puedan darme una ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Dónde/Cómo tienes definido `transaccional`?, ¿alguna razón específica para no utilizar `include` tal como lo haces con `Lockeable`? Con eso lograrías incluir el _mixin_.

Comment: Transaccional es un mixin incluido en la carpeta del proyecto. El tema es que me pidieron que agregue ese comportamiento de Transaccional utilizando metaprogramación, sin usar el include como con Lockeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé exactamente qué comportamiento buscas o por qué quieras utilizar *metaprogramación*, pero considerando que tengas un módulo `Transaccional`:

```
module Transaccional
  # métodos
end
```

Podrías lograrlo agregando el método `transaccional` a la clase `Class`, el cual se encargue de hacer el `include`; por ejemplo:

```
class Class
  def transaccional
    self.class_eval("include Transaccional")
  end
end
```

Ahora al utilizar `transaccional` dentro del cuerpo de la clase será lo mismo que utilizar `include Transaccional`.

---

Si únicamente quieres agregar el método *dinámicamente* y **sin metaprogramación** entonces lo único que tendrías que hacer es esto:

```
Persona.include(Transaccional)
```

En este caso no necesitarás poner nada en el cuerpo de la clase `Persona`:

```
class Persona
  include Lockeable

  attr_accesor :nombre, :edad
  # ...
end
```